# How to read xlsx files using fread from pydatatable?

Tags: python, pandas, xlrd, py-datatable

I have a thousands of excel files with .xlsx extentions, i'm trying to import them using fread from pydatatable.

```
fread('sample.xlsx')
```

I also have installed xlrd library in my environment.

however it gives an error as below.

```
     24     import xlrd
     25     # Fixes the warning
     26     # "PendingDeprecationWarning: This method will be removed in future
     27     #  versions.  Use 'tree.iter()' or 'list(tree.iter())' instead."
---> 28     xlrd.xlsx.ensure_elementtree_imported(False, None)
     29     xlrd.xlsx.Element_has_iter = True
     30 except ImportError:

AttributeError: module 'xlrd' has no attribute 'xlsx'
```

How to read .xlsx files using pydatatable?

Comment: it probably has to do with the xlrd version. If you can install an xlrd version earlier than 1.2 it might work. xlrd no longer supports xlsx, so an earlier version is required.

Comment: OK but as xlrd newer versions doesn't support xlsx how pydatatable would handle xlsx in future ?

Comment: I think we should ask it in their github

Comment: why don't you use `pd.read_excel()` ?

Comment: @myamulla_ciencia there is a PR on upgrading `xlrd`, but it has some performance issues. Currently the requirement is `xrld<=1.2.0`: https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/blob/main/requirements_extra.txt